# How to split and filter String with apache SPARK in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, data-science

i've been following several tutorial but i couldnt grasp the idea ( couldt apply the principle of map split filter in my example ) let say i have a String
" customer1,buy:order5" 
i want to count the number of buy words in my different strings and also the number of bought item by customers in my stream

```
            JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(",")).iterator()).filter(x -> Arrays.asList(conteneur).contains(x));
        // compte le nombre d'ads accepté et le nombre d'add refusées
        JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> nbr = words.mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<>(x,1)).reduceByKey((a,b) -> a+b);
       nbr.map((Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String>) tuple -> {

            return   String.valueOf(tuple._2) +","+tuple._1 ;}).print();
```

in this code bellow i calculate the number of buy and sell in a stream of strings like this one "customer1,buy"

i would be glad if some could explain to me

Answer (score 1):

If all your input lines are in "customer1,buy:order5" type then you can code like this:

```
int buy = sparkContext.textFile("sample-data.txt").map(s -> (s.split("buy").length - 1))
            .reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + s2).intValue();
    System.out.println(buy);
```

Comment: Your answer works perfectly but what if in my case i have a JavaStreamingContext ?

Comment: Difference between spark core and spark streaming programs is that whole input data stored and input data in comming into the process pipeline, respectively. But in both types input is converted to rdd objects then when you have rdd object you can do same transformations on it. It should work for the streaming contexxt too. The best way to find out is to test it. :)